# How to deploy angular 4 and spring boot microservice application in AWS cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I want to deploy an Angular and spring boot application (Microservice architecture) in the AWS cloud. Can anyone tell me how can I deploy it using ecs and fargate means how to connect the angular application with microservices? Or anyone knows any article/reference over the internet for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Iam pretty new to this topic to. It depends on your system architecture. If it is a basic service. I would move the application to a container and move it to the cloud. I suggest to read articles about container files like docker or orchistration tools like kubernetes.

Edit:

Try this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

Comment: I just want to know like how we can deploy microservices on AWS cloud or what are the different approaches we can use for it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, i assume that you have 'angular app', Service1, service 2 etc where each services running  independent to each other.

1. Create Elastic Load balancer (public).
2. Independent Spring boot services (Dockerize), deploy in ECS and attach to the load balancer as a path (Path Based routing) where each services have the servlet paths ex: /service1*, /service2* etc.

Angular - Dockerize it (nginx as base image) configure the server(microservice) endpoint of ELB (created above) in the environment variable. -  this is because usually javascript codes will be executing in the browser and need a public URL for it to fetch the data from the microservices.

Also add this angular docker to an ELB (path based routing /*).
Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html

Hope this helps.